# I am not able to create transition in input box by transforming label

Tags: javascript, html, css

**the input box is using focus already,input and label tags are not using the css style provided earlier in style tag?
transform not working :(**
i have bold where i am not getting,
i have provided my css and html
i used input and label> then style them in css but it doesnot work then I created transition and it does not work more over it took it as default in page

**Code I tried:**

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.searchdiv {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    /* border: 2px solid red; */
}

.search {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.349);
    background: rgba(211, 210, 210, 0.705);
}

label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.search:focus,
.search:valid {
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgba(85, 206, 247, 0.699);
}

#searchbar:focus~label,
#searchbar:valid~label {
    transform: translatey(-10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="searchdiv">
        <input type="text" id="searchbar" class="search"><label for="searchbar">Search</label>
    </div>
    <div><button class="btn srchbtn">SEARCH</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood correctly what you want to do

**Option 1 - CSS**

The changes made are in `.search:focus` and `#searchbar:focus+label`
But after the input field is out of focus the inscription "Search" will return to its original place.

*If you want the change to happen once view **Option 2** below*

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.searchdiv {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    /* border: 2px solid red; */
}

.search {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.349);
    background: rgba(211, 210, 210, 0.705);
}

label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.search:focus {
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgba(85, 206, 247, 0.699);
}

#searchbar:focus + label {
    transform: translatey(-20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="searchdiv">
        <input type="text" id="searchbar" class="search">
        <label for="searchbar">Search</label>
    </div>
    <div><button class="btn srchbtn">SEARCH</button></div>
</div>
```

**Option 2 - JS and CSS**

If you want the transition to be one-time after clicking the in input element you must use JS. This script will add style to the `label` element with id `searchbarLabel` when clicked into the `input` element with id `searchbar`.

```js
document.getElementById("searchbar").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var y = document.getElementById("searchbarLabel");
    y.setAttribute('style', 'transform: translatey(-20px);')
});
```

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.searchdiv {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    /* border: 2px solid red; */
}

.search {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.349);
    background: rgba(211, 210, 210, 0.705);
}

label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.search:focus {
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgba(85, 206, 247, 0.699);
}

/* 
#searchbar:focus+label {
    transform: translatey(-20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="searchdiv">
        <input type="text" id="searchbar" class="search">
        <label for="searchbar" id="searchbarLabel">Search</label>
    </div>
    <div><button class="btn srchbtn">SEARCH</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: #searchbar:valid + label  when i am using this with focus to keep the label where it is after transition its not working. :(

Comment: I added a description and option 2 with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Something that is better practice is too not put label inside input and also in the css try making it more specific like :

```
.main . searchdiv input /* for example */
```

other than that I can't really help if you repost with cleaner code and better code maybe we can help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the transform works. If you think its your browser settings, try adding a reset.css similar to this:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```